# we have found two error message when I am Upload same name file .But I want to be only one error message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

we have found two error messages when I Upload the same name file. But I want to be only one error message.

```js
const checkFileName=(name)=>{
  // for(let i=0; i<blobs.length;i++ ){
    let status=0;
    blobs.map(function(element){
      // console.log(element.name.split("/")[1]);
      if(element.name.split("/")[1]==name){
        // console.log(element.name.split("/")[1]);
        status=1;
      }
  })
   
  // }
  if(status==1){
    return true;
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of information to understand what you are trying to achieve:
What is `blob` ? Where is the function `checkFileName` called ? Where do you see your *error message* ?

Answer (score 0):

In your index.js file, if You see

```
 <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
```

You need to remove both the 'React.SctrictMode' lines from the file in order to avoid your error messages or console.log() prints to repeat themselves. Please try and tell if this resolves your query.

Comment: issue will be not resolved  after that.

Comment: Then please tell more about what errors are coming and what is the error that you want.

Comment: I am getting to twice pop up message within the same time but I am want only one popup message .

Comment: Use a "flag=false" variable to check if the name is present or not because if you are directly comparing the name, it will compare with all the names and throw a false as many times as it doesn't match. Use a flag variable and break the loop when "flag" is true that will be when name is matched.

Comment: I am trying to use flag but I am not find solutions . Can you send me the code ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I meant by using a flag variable.

```
const checkFileName=(name)=>{
  let flag = false;
  for(let i=0; i<blobs.length;i++ ){
      // console.log(element.name.split("/")[1]);
      if(element.name.split("/")[1]==name){
        // console.log(element.name.split("/")[1]);
        flag = true;
        break;
      }
  }
  if(flag){
    return true;
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

Please try this and tell if your code works or not.

Comment: 'element' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: its your code's modification only.